# msvc2013 can't compile header file containing huge lookup table

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, lookup-tables

I have a header-only library which contains a massive look-up table (more than a million doubles). The look-up table is defined:

```
#ifndef EGM96LUT_h__
#define EGM96LUT_h__

#include <vector>

namespace coord
{
    const std::vector<std::vector<double>> EGM96LUT = {{...},{...},...};
}

#endif
```

When I try to compile things which include this header with visual studio, it hangs for a very long time then crashes. I can build the same code in gcc in about 10 seconds.

I know this would probably work if I compiled the LUT statically inside a .cpp file, but I *really* don't want to break the header-only-ness of the library. I also know I could store the data in some type of .dat file and read it from disk, but I'm trying to avoid that as well and keep everything compiled.

Is there a workaround that might help the build time but without the use of a .cpp?

Comment: _"I know this would probably work if I compiled the LUT statically inside a .cpp file"_ I very much doubt it would make a blind bit of difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally used vectors so the LUT would be heap-allocated, as I was worried about possibly overflowing the stack. Refactoring the vector as a const array solved the issue, and didn't overflow.

```
const double EGM96LUT[721][1441] = {{...},{...},...};
```

Comment: Because globals have nothing to do with the stack (another example of why using "stack"/"heap" terminology to loosely describe "I didn't write `new`"/"I wrote `new`" is very bad)

Comment: wouldn't the global data be in data segment rather than on stack?

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich I think you are correct, but I'll leave my answer alone in case someone else makes the same mistake due to the same misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can always break it up.  Generate internal vectors one at a time (use your favorite scripting language to generate this long text) and then store them in the outer vector.

Since, from your description, it is the parser that's crashing, this would solve it because it would give it less to chew on.

It might also work to change it to

```
const std::vector<const std::vector<double> >
```

Because that's really what the 2-dimensional array stores.

Comment: The question doesn't meantion stack.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, the author's answer to own question does mention that he was using vectors to avoid overflowing the stack.

Comment: Ok that's a bit confusing if you're responding to another answer in your own answer :)

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit,  you are right.  I'll move that part to a comment on the answer.